# Whole-word matching using regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want a C++ regex that matches "bananas" or "pajamas" but not "bananas2" or "bananaspajamas" or "banana" or basically anything besides those exact two words. So I did this:

```
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  static const std::regex bp = std::regex("\bbananas\b|\bpajamas\b");
  printf("%d\n", std::regex_match("bananas", bp));
}
```

Except it printed 0! What gives? `/\bbananas\b|\bpajamas\b/.test('bananas')` gives me `true` in Javascript so what's different about C++?

Comment: Double up the ``\`` in `\b`. Currently, you are specify the backspace character. Since you are specifying a string to the regex constructor, you need to make sure the regex constructor sees the correct string - if you want the constructor to see `\b` or `\s`, you need to write `"\\b"` or `"\\s"` in the string. There is also the raw string construct in C++11, IIRC

Answer (score 5):

Regex string should have `\bbananas\b|\bpajamas\b`. but in c++, `"\bbananas\b|\bpajamas\b"` return `bbananasb|bpajamasb`. for this reason, you have to use extra `\` with `\` like `"\\bbananas\\b|\\bpajamas\\b"`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a regular expression for this. If you want to find out whether a string is one of two words, just use a straightforward equality comparison:

```
if (str == "bananas" || str == "pajamas") {
    // OK
}
```

If you have more possibilities, you can use some sort of a set:

```
const std::unordered_set<std::string> words {
    "bananas",
    "pajamas",
    "papayas"
};

if (words.find(str) != words.end()) {
    // OK
}
```