# Whole-word matching with regex.h

Tags: c++, regex

I want a C++ regex that matches "bananas" or "pajamas" but not "bananas2" or "bananaspajamas" or "banana" or basically anything besides those exact two words. So I did this:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  regex_t rexp;

  int rv = regcomp(&rexp, "\\bbananas\\b|\\bpajamas\\b", REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB);
  if (rv != 0) {
    printf("Abandon hope, all ye who enter here\n");
  }
  regmatch_t match;
  int diditmatch = regexec(&rexp, "bananas", 1, &match, 0);
  printf("%d %d\n", diditmatch, REG_NOMATCH);
}
```

and it printed `1 1` as if there wasn't a match. What happened? I also tried `\bbananas\b|\bpajamas\b` for my regex and that failed too.

I asked [Whole-word matching using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064732/whole-word-matching-regex-in-c) about std::regex, but std::regex is awful and slow so I'm trying regex.h.

Comment: I don’t get why this gets downvoted. It’s a small, nice, self-contained question with compiling, minimal code explaining the problem. Furthermore, the OP has read the documentation at least superficially. **What more do people want?!**

Comment: I don't understand either. The *question* is not a poor one.

Comment: I think the question is downvoted because you specify C++, and your code is actually C.

Comment: @stribizhev Well the question mentions specifically why the code isn’t more C++-y, namely that the current C++ API and implementation for regex … *stinks*.

Comment: @stribizhev If the code is being compiled through a `C++` compiler, then its `C++` regardless if it could *also* be compiled with a `C` compiler..

Comment: I agree with everyone, I am also interested in a solution. This is also why I upvoted the question.

Comment: I can't repeat this it printed `0 1` for me.

Answer (score 1):

[The POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) specifies neither word boundary syntax nor look-behind and look-ahead syntax (which could be used to emulate a word boundary) for both BRE and ERE. Therefore, **it's not possible to write a regex with word boundaries that works across different POSIX-compliant platforms**.

For a portable solution, you should consider using PCRE, or Boost.Regex if you plan to code in C++.

Otherwise, you are stuck with a non-portable solution. If you are fine with such restriction, there are several alternatives:

- If you link with GNU C library, [it extends the syntax to include word boundary, among other things](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions): `\b` (word boundary), `\B` (non word boundary), `\<` (start of word), `\>` (end of word).
- Some systems extends the BRE and ERE grammar to include `[[:<:]]` (start of word), `[[:>:]]` (end of word) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Konrad left a great answer that solved my problem but it disappeared somehow so I can't accept it. Here's the code that printed the right thing, for posterity:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  regex_t rexp;

  int rv = regcomp(&rexp, "[[:<:]]bananas[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]pajamas[[:>:]]", REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB);
  if (rv != 0) {
    printf("Abandon hope, all ye who enter here\n");
  }
  regmatch_t match;
  int diditmatch = regexec(&rexp, "bananas", 1, &match, 0);
  printf("%d %d\n", diditmatch, REG_NOMATCH);
}
```

Comment: Konrad states in a comment that this construction works on one system but not on another, so it appears library implementation depending. So not a problem if it works with your system and you don't need to be able to compile it elsewhere. If you do, you should look for an expression that is better supported.

Comment: `[[:<:]]` is not part of the POSIX standard. It seems to be an extension. Konrad said in the last comment before deleting his post (and I also reproduced it afterwards), this syntax doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: GNU has several [**extensions**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) `\<`, `\>`, `\b` which can be used here - but since they are extensions, they only work if you link to GNU library, which might not be available on all systems.

Answer (score -1):

Use

`s == "balances" || s == "pajamas"`

instead where `s` is a `std::string`.

Regular expressions can overcomplicate a simple solution. Avoid them in particular if you want a fixed match.

Comment: “Regular expressions can overcomplicate a simple solution.” — That’s not usually the case though. Case in point, OP is *probably* not really interested in bananas and pajamas, and this is a simplified example (that said, yes, fixed matches shouldn’t warrant a regex in general).

Comment: Jamie Zawinski: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Yes, I hate jwz for that quote. It’s completely, utterly wrong and people quote it as dogma.

Comment: Right thanks but as Konrad hypothesizes there's more to it than I'm letting on here and long story short I need the regex version.

Comment: Do feel free to edit the question. If you're still only wanting to check that a word is is in a predefined set then I'd still avoid regular expressions.

Comment: If you edit out the *specific* phrase "I want a C++ regex ..." then this would be a good answer. As it is, it does not answer the question or offer an explanation; it offers another way instead. Whether or not this is acceptable to the OP is up to him. See also Meta-SO: [OP asked about problems after using X; the right answer is “use Y instead”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275913/2564301).